# Android listview get item textview

Tags: android, listview

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in listView1.Items)
{             
    for (int i = 0; i < itemRow.SubItems.Count; i++) 
    {
        string dueDate = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
        MessageBox.Show(dueDate);
    }
}
```

Andoroid how to? 
In a Baseadapter? 
My code worked fine,
first getting all records and list listview with textviews.
And I handle (in an adapter class) click event id,name.. Etc and setText item insert database not problem here but;
if I press back button and reload this page then, lost item

My main java:

```
String query = "select * from xx where xxx = '" + xxx + "'";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     while (rs.next()) {
          lst.add(new lt(rs.getString("xx"), rs.getString("xx").toString(), 1));
     }
myAdaptor adaptor = new myAdaptor(this, lyt);
listView.setAdapter(adaptor);
```

Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Table"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:id="@+id/txtmasaad"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Okey"
        android:id="@+id/btnonay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/btnk"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Go back"
        android:id="@+id/btngeri"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

myAdapter class

```
public class OzelAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    List<lt> list;
    Activity activity;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    int urunAdet=0;

    public myAdaptor(Activity activity, List<lt> mList) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        list = mList;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View sView;
        sView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sat, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) sView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView tv = (TextView) sView.findViewById(R.id.tvnm);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) sView.findViewById(R.id.tvfm);
        final TextView tvadet = (TextView) sView.findViewById(R.id.texw);
        final Button button = (Button) sView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        final lt lst = list.get(position);
        tv.setText(lt.getnm().toString());
        tv2.setText(lt.getf().toString());
```

/...

myAdapter layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:background="@drawable/backg"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1.13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="26dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kahve"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvfm"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 TL"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/click"
      android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My saved items:

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/knLZJv.png))</sub>

Reload (back items):

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/PP6v6v.png))</sub>

The problem:

[image: 3]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/0mNbnW.png))</sub>

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I add image link my question

Comment: I handle  iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { and set tvadet.setText(Integer.toString(urunAdet));
                        tvadet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: But I need page load handle, if item exist database then set item number on screen back.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I don't have point please edit my question.